# Cannot get correct characters from Excel (utf8 formatted) into PHP

Tags: php, excel, utf-8, character-encoding

There are lots of questions and answers to all kind of character encoding problems, but none of them seems to solve my problem.

I get a spreadsheet every month which needs to be converted to Prestashop data. I still help myself by first converting the .xls to .csv, but it would be so much easier if I could do it in one go.

I use PHP-ExcelReader for reading the .xls file which is saved in Unicode (UTF-8).
My problem is that whatever output encoding I choose, there is always a number of characters that will not show up properly.

I have created a test page to show exactly what is happening under what conditions:
http://www.num1.nl/test.php

Hope someone can help out.

Comment: what happens when you change the internal encoding to UTF8 as well? And sent a (meta) header with the encoding?

Comment: As far as I know excel cannot save as UTF8 encoding

Comment: Check for it on the Save As dialog, I believe some versions have had it there.

Comment: Use phpExcel instead to read straight from the Excel file.

Comment: @John, utf8 headers are sent, and internal encoding makes no difference.

Comment: @Ateszki, as advermark writes, there is an option in the save as dialog of excel to save a document in all kinds of encodings

Comment: @Captain Payalytic, phpExcel seemed like huge overkill for what I need. But I will have a look at it.

Comment: For interest, not all the characters in your spreadsheet are correctly decoded in Excel2003.

Comment: Looking at the raw binaries of the file. The UTF-8 bytes for `Ð` (`C390`) are nowhere to be found in the file. However, the UTF-16LE (Unicode Encoding in Microsoft speak) bytes for `Ð` (`D000`) are found exactly once. Coincidence?

Comment: I never even thought of questioning the input data. I simply open the sheet and save it as UTF-8, thinking that would be enough. Learned some valuable lessons again :)

Answer (score 1):

@grahamj42, I know it doesn't but all characters I need are handled correctly. Just for the test setup it was easier to display the full range.

@Captain Payalytic, phpExcel indeed did the trick for me. All essential characters are treated correctly now.

Now I only need to figure out why phpExcel expands my data range with 1 row.

Thanks so much for the tip :)